# Is there anyway to see what was the first value that the user typed using Scanf?

Tags: c, int, scanf, do-while

I'm struggling to find a way to know what was the first value that the user typed using scanf on C. For instance

```
int main () {
    printf("Type your number:\n");
    int number;

    do{
        scanf("%d", &number);
    }while (number != 0);
    return 0 ;
}
```

I wanna somehow check if the FIRST number that the user typed was the same the he typed last before typing 0 to end the program

Comment: you can use an iterator and check the condition like if(i==1) and store the value and then compare. If you want to check for the first and the last value just make conditions for them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add couple of variables, one to keep track of the first value and the second to keep track of whether the first value has already been stored.

```
int main ()
{
   int isFirstValueEntered = 0;
   int firstNumber;
   int number;

   do {
      printf("Type your number:\n");

      // If there was an error in reading the number, break out of the loop.
      if ( scanf("%d", &number) != 1 )
      {
         break;
      }

      if ( !isFirstValueEntered )
      {
         firstNumber = number;
         isFirstValueEntered = 1;
      }
   }while (number != 0);

   // Now you can use the first number that the user entered.
   if ( isFirstValueEntered )
   {
      printf("The first number: %d\n", firstNumber);
   }

   return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a checker for first and last and save them, something like:

```
int main () {
  printf("Type your number:\n");
  int number;
  int firstN=0,lastN=0, checker=0;

  do{
  scanf("%d", &number);
  if(checker==0) //only takes first number then stops
    {
      firstN = number;
      checker = 1;
    }
  if(number != 0)//if it is a 0 it will not save it and loop will break, it will hold last value enterd
    {
      lastN = number;
    }
  }while (number != 0);

   if(firstN == lastN) printf("You first and last numbers were %d, they match",number);
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: This code will always return the lastN=0

Comment: ah, sorry.. fixed it

Comment: Did it before you.

Comment: Note that if the first character entered was `'x'`, you could have an infinite loop.  Best to check the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
int main () {
  printf("Type your number:\n");
  int number=0,count=1,fno,lno;

  do{
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if(count==1){
      fno=number;
    }
    count++;
    if(number!=0){
      lno=number;
    }
  }while (number != 0);

  printf("\nFirst Number=%d\nLast Number=%d",fno,lno);

  if(fno==lno) {
    printf("\nFirst and last number match.");
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Note that if the first character entered was `'x'`, you could have an infinite loop.  Best to check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Even if the character was x then %d in the scanf will take the ASCII value of it, which will be in integer I think. And how it can run in an infinite loop.

Comment: "if the character was x then %d in the scanf will take the ASCII value of it" --> No, `number` will be unchanged.  `number`, being uninitialized, may have a non-zero value in it, causing the loop to run again.  With `'x'` still sitting in `stdin`, the process repeats - infinite loop.  Good code checks the return values from input functions like `scanf()`.